# How to sync cursor at Gantt amcharts and Serial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm using this example to sync AmCharts Gantt and Serial:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/sync-serial-gantt-chart/

But how can I also sync the cursor?

I have both with date in axes:

[image: Serial]

[image: Gantt]

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
var __handleCursorChange = function(event)
{
  var charts = AmCharts.charts;
  event.chart.lastCursorPosition = event.index;
  for (var x in charts)
  {
    var chart = charts[x];
    if (event.chart !== chart)
    {
      if(event.chart.type !== 'gantt')
      {
        if(chart.type !== 'gantt')
        {
          chart.chartCursor.syncWithCursor(event.chart.chartCursor);
        }
        else
          {
          var timestamp = event.chart.chartCursor.timestamp;
          console.log('passing over serial',
            timestamp,
            moment(timestamp).format(dateFormatDB)
          );
          chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(new Date(timestamp));
          //chart.addChartCursor(event.chart.chartCursor);
        }
      }
      else
        {
        console.log(
          'passing over gantt',
          event.chart.categoryAxis.xToIndex(),
          event.chart.valueAxis.getCoordinate()
          /*event.chart.valueAxis.getCoordinate(),
          event.chart.CategoryAxis,
          event.chart.CategoryAxis.coordinateToDate()*/
        );
        chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(event.chart.valueAxis.getCoordinate());
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't sync gantt and serial cursors. Gantt charts use the value axis for dates and there isn't a showCursorAt/syncCursor-compatible method for a value axis cursor to enable cursor syncing like in two serial charts. Your best bet is to convert your gantt chart into a serial floating column chart like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/v5oLdv7h/) or [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6q068dvk/3/) and use [`syncWithCursor` to sync them](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-syncwithcursor-sync-cursor-across-several-serial-charts/) or use `showCursorAt`.

Comment: @xorspark oh, this is sad... In the example you gave, isn't possible to have two values in the same position on the x line, just as gantt can, right?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Sorry. Serial's a bit limited with this workaround as well. I'd recommend just sticking to syncing the zoom and ignore the cursor syncing since adding this functionality to the gantt chart won't happen in v3.